# Get data from clickhouse to grafana

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I can’t get data from the clickhouse database to Grafana. I have tried various settings of the data source: various access options, various authorization options. And, did not get any results.

I have made the settings in the Grafana like this:

[image]

This is my request. If I copy it and execute it on the clickhouse console, then I get the data. That is, the request is formed rules.

[image]

ClickHouse database is on localhost:8123 (in console: curl 'http://localhost:8123/'     Ok.)

Grafana is on `localhost:3000.`
All services are on the same machine.

I am using clickhouse server `version 20.1.4 revision 54431` and `grafana 6.6.2.`

Comment: But what is the issue exactly?

Comment: what you mean "can't get data"? 
according to your screenshots, I don't see any error message
maybe do you mean "I get an empty dataset for my query"?

could you try to run your query via `clickhouse-client`?

Comment: @RomanShan it looks like the problem in *HTTP -> Access* -field - need to use option **Server (default)** instead of *Browser*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a release bug.

it works correctly with Grafana 6 before the latest update from GrafanaLabs that seem to break the compatibility.

see: https://github.com/Vertamedia/clickhouse-grafana/issues/171